# How to set text on table columns to left or right?

Tags: css

I have table

```
%table{:class=>'table'}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th ID
      %th Email
      %th Welcome Shown?
  %tbody
  - @user.each do |user|
    %tr
      %td= publisher.id
      %td= publisher.email
      %td= publisher.was_welcome_message_shown
```

I want to set not all columns as "text-align:center", some columns should be "text-align:right"

Any suggestions with css?

Comment: If you're asking about CSS, please don't tag it [sass]. And which columns do you want to be center-aligned and which right-aligned?

Comment: NP, %td= publisher.id
    %td= publisher.email should be "text-align:left\right" and  %td= publisher.was_welcome_message_shown should be "text-align:center".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of publisher.id

```
%td{:class=>'txt-lft'}= publisher.id
```

CSS

```
.txt-lft { text-align: left; }
```